# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working after search

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar

Am using the code below to search through a tableView

```
  func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredProducts = food.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text.store_name
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filteredProducts.count == 0){
        inSearchMode = false;
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("searchText \(searchText)")

}
```

And my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this

```
        var foo: Food!
        if inSearchMode{
            foo = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
        }else{
            foo = food[indexPath.row]
        }
```

An here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
 var foo:Food!

    if inSearchMode{
        foo = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        foo = food[indexPath.row]
    }
```

But when i select any row after searching the data from another row is displayed. It is not showing the row data i passes to another view it is showing another view own

Comment: Are you sure about `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code? :)

Comment: I would suggest using just one array to keep track of the items being shown/selected. You should keep the full list, and just populate the filteredProducts to simplify the code.

Comment: As an unimportant side note: I would structure my code [this](https://youtu.be/SgEO7nni5CQ?t=2318) way. See the exact moment. He is using didSet + reloadData in a more effective way

Comment: Have you confirmed inSearchMode is false within cellForForAtIndexPath once the search has finished? Also where is your code for numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: @JakeHolland if you're suggesting not having a second `food` array how would you retrieve the items that were filtered out, once the user clears the search/backspaces?

Comment: @ConnorNeville You have a callback from the searchbar, so something like this. 

`if(searchText.length > 0){ 
filteredProducts = food.filter({ (text) -> Bool in let tmp: NSString = text.store_name let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) return range.location != NSNotFound }) } else { filteredProducts = food } self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Okay, so you still have a second `food` array that you're filtering from.